# Geany Terminal has the characters spaced out for some reason

Tags: geany

When I was playing around with terminal settings, my terminal started spacing out the characters a lot. I haven't played around with Geany settings other than that and I use it for C++. The computer I'm running Geany on is a Macbook Pro 14" M1 Pro. Also, a black bar was intentionally put over some text in the terminal because it was my name. [Terminal with spaced out text for no good reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWk5w.jpg) [Terminal settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M9nK.png)

I tried changing the settings back to default for the terminal, didn't work. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Geany. I tried restarting my computer and opening the app. Maybe resetting Geany would work, but I don't know how to do it on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to reset Geany to fix the issue. First I typed in, "defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles true", into the Terminal, then I typed in "killall Finder". This allowed me to see the ".config" folder which was hidden. I then went into Finder, where on the top menu I pressed "Go" "Go to Folder...", typed in "/users/" and went to the ".config" folder in my user account. I then deleted the geany folder inside of it and it reset all my settings which fixed the issue. Don't change the terminal font from Menlo.